# Stuck in the loading in ref.watch.when

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Im trying to buildsuggestion in the searchdelegate class with some data from riverpod

```
    ref.watch(searchCommunityProvider(query)).when(
        data: (communites) {
          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: communites.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final community = communites[index];
              return ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(community.avatar),
                ),
                title: Text('r/${community.name}'),
                onTap: () => navigateToCommunity(context, community.name),
              );
            },
          );
        },
        error: (error, stackTrace) => ErrorText(
          error: error.toString(),
        ),
        loading: () => const Loader(),
      ),
```

Provider:

```
     final searchCommunityProvider = StreamProvider.family((ref, String query) {
     return  ref.watch(communityControllerProvider.notifier).searchCommunity(query);
     });
     
     Stream<List<Community>> searchCommunity(String query) {
     return _communityRepository.searchCommunity(query);
     }
```

SearchCommunity in communityRepository:

```
     Stream<List<Community>> searchCommunity(String query) {
print(query);
return _communities
    .where(
      'name',
      isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: query.isEmpty ? 0 : query,
      isLessThan: query.isEmpty
          ? null
          : query.substring(0, query.length - 1) +
              String.fromCharCode(
                query.codeUnitAt(query.length - 1) + 1,
              ),
    )
    .snapshots()
    .map((event) {
  List<Community> communities = [];
  for (var community in event.docs) {
    communities
        .add(Community.fromMap(community.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
  }
  return communities;
});
}
```

Searching anything in the search bar remains stuck infinitely until i remove the search and retype (or even removing the keyboard works) it then the result is shown.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello! You haven't given enough information to determine the cause. It'd be helpful to share the entire widget using this `when` call, and possibly the provider.

Comment: This is the buildsuggestion function used in SearchDelegate class

Comment: @RémiRousselet i have added additional code for further explaination